# jQuery: show html elements when a disabled select menu is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

In my application users can edit information for their reservation but I don't want them to change the type of reservation. So I have thought to load a page with a select menu displaying the type of reservation but it is also disabled. What I would like to happen is that on page load if the select menu is disabled then the relative elements are showed according to the selected but disabled type. Reading the documentation this is what I have thought I need:

```
jQuery("#tipologia_piazzola").load(function(){
    alert("something");

    if (this.value == "mensile" && this.is(":disabled")) {
        jQuery(".both").show();
        jQuery(".mensile").show();
        jQuery(".giornaliera").hide();
    }

});
```

Obviously I have inserted it inside the ready function but neither the alert nor the html elements appear. Is this the correct way? Or, how can I reach my goal?

Comment: As far as i know `.load` is depricated in newer version of jQuery. which version are you using here?

Comment: .load needs a remote url to fetch from you are just passing the call back function which executes after the url has been succesfully fetched.

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.7...ok, .load() is not the right method. Do you know which I can use to get what I want?

Comment: Can you give us the HTML.?

Comment: here it is if you want to have a look http://pastebin.com/LqPJzewB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `jQuery(this)` instead of `this` to call `is(':disabled')` function because it need jQuery object and not javascript object. Also use `document.ready` as shown below to ensure that all DOM element is ready.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var $this = jQuery('#tipologia_piazzola');
    if ($this.val() == "mensile" && $this.is(":disabled")) {
            jQuery(".both").show();
            jQuery(".mensile").show();
            jQuery(".giornaliera").hide();
        }
});
```

**NOTE** : - please exclude `document.ready` if you have it already and put above code in your existing `document.ready`

Comment: I'm afrai it doesn't work...maybe .load() is not the right method

Comment: I had already put the jQuery call inside the ready function... :S

Comment: I have updated my code ,  where i am taking object of `tipologia_piazzola` and then calling `.val()` and `.is(":disabled")`. pls try now by putting above code (excluding document.ready as this already there in your code)

Comment: oh, it works...great! Thank you by heart...sorry for my mess, I have just started using js and jQuery. I didn't even know there was a difference between $ and jQuery()...I just thought $ was an abbreviation for the second